# Crashing Visual Studio Live Unit Testing

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, live-unit-tests

I´m a new user in **stackoverflow** and this is my problem:

As part of my work, we recently installed VS 2017 Enterprise Edition. Everything was fine untill few weeks ago the ***Live Unit Testing*** module stop working.

Does enyone was able to resolve this kind of problems?

This is the output console:

`[17:26:23.170 Info] Live Unit Testing started.
[17:26:23.229 Error] - FatalError - System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: key
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.LiveUnitTesting.AugmentedProjectDependencyGraph.AddDependencies(ProjectGraphNode projectNode)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.LiveUnitTesting.AugmentedProjectDependencyGraph.EnsureDirectDependencies()
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.LiveUnitTesting.AugmentedProjectDependencyGraph.GetBuildOrder(Solution solution, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.LiveUnitTesting.BuildManagement.BuildManagerState.<BuildAsync>d__35.MoveNext()
[17:26:24.099 Info] Live Unit Testing stopped.`

[Output Console Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nrMU.png)

**Thanks for yor time!**

Comment: We need to see your code. But the error message tells you exactly where the issue is and also what the issue is. My guess from the message is that youre trying to add a new item to a dictionary with a null key

Comment: It looks like the exception is not actually coming from a failing unit test but from Live Unit Testing framework (Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.LiveUnitTesting.AugmentedProjectDependencyGraph.AddDependencies). I get the same exception despite all the unit tests passing when I run them manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can try deleting the saved data as recommended at https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/test/live-unit-testing?view=vs-2017, it worked for me.
[image]