# Visual Studio 2019 Live Unit Testing Crashes

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2019, live-unit-tests

I'm trying to use Live Unit Testing with my nUnit tests, but it crashes every time I start it.  It crashes whether I start it manually or on solution load.  I've restarted VS multiple times, reinstalled it, [deleted the persisted data per this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63955708/127888) and now I'm out of ideas.

Output Window

```
[15:23:48.443 Info] Live Unit Testing started.
[15:23:48.471 Info] Building solution.
[15:23:52.493 Info] - BuildManager - Build performance issue: compiler called to produce 
 'C:\git\Wa531.SAR_Log\.vs\Wa531.SAR_Log\v16\lut\0\i\Wa531.SAR_Log\
   Debug\netstandard2.1\Wa531.SAR_Log.dll' 
again after build already succeeded.
[15:23:53.205 Info] Build completed with failures. Errors were logged under 
   'C:\git\Wa531.SAR_Log\.vs\Wa531.SAR_Log\v16\lut\0\diag\'.
[15:23:58.971 Info] Started executing tests from 
   C:\git\Wa531.SAR_Log\.vs\Wa531.SAR_Log\v16\lut\0\t\Wa531.SAR_Log.Tests\
   Debug\netcoreapp3.1\Wa531.SAR_Log.Tests.dll. 
[15:24:00.741 Info] Finished executing tests. (Passed: 24, Failed: 0, Skipped: 0, Not Executed: 0)
[15:24:05.156 Error] Live Unit Testing is being turned off because a process that it depends on has
   either exited unexpectedly or encountered an unrecoverable exception. Restart Visual Studio before
   trying to start Live Unit Testing again.
[15:24:05.156 Error] Log files present in the '%Temp%\servicehub\logs' folder may contain information 
   that can help diagnose this problem.
[15:24:05.196 Info] Live Unit Testing stopped.
```

%Temp%\servicehub\logs

```
01/02/2021 15:20:09 Pacific Standard Time: Warning : 14 :Aborting pending request "2" because 
   the connection was lost.
01/02/2021 15:20:09 Pacific Standard Time: Warning : 14 :Aborting pending request "12" because 
   the connection was lost.
```

Build.log

```
[15:23:52.493 Info]
 - BuildManager - Build performance issue: compiler called to 
   produce 'C:\git\Wa531.SAR_Log\.vs\Wa531.SAR_Log\v16\lut\0\i\Wa531.SAR_Log\
   Debug\netstandard2.1\Wa531.SAR_Log.dll' again after build already succeeded.
[15:23:53.183 Verbose] 
- BuildManager - 
   C:\Users\willi\.nuget\packages\resizetizer.nt\0.2.0\buildTransitive\
   Resizetizer.NT.targets(155,3): error : One or more errors occurred.
[15:23:53.186 Verbose] 
- BuildManager - Some of the file paths defined in the 
   csproj under the Live Unit Testing build path are missing. Verify whether 
   these files should be present under the Live Unit Testing build path and if 
   necessary update the csproj definition to look these files up in a 
   different place.
[15:23:53.188 Verbose] 
- BuildManager - Item _OutputPathItem 
   'C:\git\Wa531.SAR_Log\.vs\Wa531.SAR_Log\v16\lut\0\b\Wa531.SAR_Log\
   Wa531.SAR_Log.Android\bin\Debug\' evaluated via:
     _OutputPathItem: '$(OutDir)' @ C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual 
       Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\
       Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets:275
  OutDir: 'C:\git\Wa531.SAR_Log\.vs\Wa531.SAR_Log\v16\lut\0\b\
           Wa531.SAR_Log\Wa531.SAR_Log.Android\bin\Debug\' 
           @ C:\git\Wa531.SAR_Log\Wa531.SAR_Log\Wa531.SAR_Log.Android\
             Wa531.SAR_Log.Android.csproj:0
[15:23:53.188 Verbose] 
- BuildManager - Item AppConfigFileDestination 
    'C:\git\Wa531.SAR_Log\.vs\Wa531.SAR_Log\v16\lut\0\b\Wa531.SAR_Log\
    Wa531.SAR_Log.Android\bin\Debug\Wa531.SAR_Log.Android.dll.config' 
    evaluated via:
     AppConfigFileDestination: '$(OutDir)$(TargetFileName).config' 
      @ C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild
\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets:306
  OutDir: 'C:\git\Wa531.SAR_Log\.vs\Wa531.SAR_Log\v16\lut\0\b\
     Wa531.SAR_Log\Wa531.SAR_Log.Android\bin\Debug\' 
     @ C:\git\Wa531.SAR_Log\Wa531.SAR_Log\Wa531.SAR_Log.Android\
       Wa531.SAR_Log.Android.csproj:0
  TargetFileName: '$(TargetName)$(TargetExt)' @ C:\Program Files (x86)\
    Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\
    Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets:213
  TargetName: '$(AssemblyName)' @ C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\
    2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\
    Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets:205
  AssemblyName: 'Wa531.SAR_Log.Android' @ 
      C:\git\Wa531.SAR_Log\Wa531.SAR_Log\Wa531.SAR_Log.Android\
      Wa531.SAR_Log.Android.csproj:14
  TargetExt: '.dll' @ C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\
      Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets:184
[15:23:53.188 Verbose] 
- BuildManager - Item _DebugSymbolsOutputPath 'C:\git\Wa531.SAR_Log\.vs\Wa531.SAR_Log\v16\lut\0\b\Wa531.SAR_Log\Wa531.SAR_Log.Android\bin\Debug\Wa531.SAR_Log.Android.pdb' evaluated via:
_DebugSymbolsOutputPath: '@(_DebugSymbolsIntermediatePath->'$(OutDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')' @ C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets:375
  OutDir: 'C:\git\Wa531.SAR_Log\.vs\Wa531.SAR_Log\v16\lut\0\b\Wa531.SAR_Log\Wa531.SAR_Log.Android\bin\Debug\' @ C:\git\Wa531.SAR_Log\Wa531.SAR_Log\Wa531.SAR_Log.Android\Wa531.SAR_Log.Android.csproj:0
[15:23:53.188 Verbose] 
- BuildManager - Item _ApplicationManifestFinal 'C:\git\Wa531.SAR_Log\.vs\Wa531.SAR_Log\v16\lut\0\b\Wa531.SAR_Log\Wa531.SAR_Log.Android\bin\Debug\Native.Wa531.SAR_Log.Android.manifest' evaluated via:
_ApplicationManifestFinal: '$(OutDir)$(_DeploymentTargetApplicationManifestFileName)' @ C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets:413
  OutDir: 'C:\git\Wa531.SAR_Log\.vs\Wa531.SAR_Log\v16\lut\0\b\Wa531.SAR_Log\Wa531.SAR_Log.Android\bin\Debug\' @ C:\git\Wa531.SAR_Log\Wa531.SAR_Log\Wa531.SAR_Log.Android\Wa531.SAR_Log.Android.csproj:0
  _DeploymentTargetApplicationManifestFileName: 'Native.$(AssemblyName).manifest' @ C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets:229
    AssemblyName: 'Wa531.SAR_Log.Android' @ C:\git\Wa531.SAR_Log\Wa531.SAR_Log\Wa531.SAR_Log.Android\Wa531.SAR_Log.Android.csproj:14
```

VS Info

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2019
Version 16.8.3
VisualStudio.16.Release/16.8.3+30804.86
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.8.03752

Installed Version: Enterprise

Visual C++ 2019   00435-60000-00000-AA025
Microsoft Visual C++ 2019

ADL Tools Service Provider   1.0
ASA Service Provider   1.0
ASP.NET and Web Tools 2019   16.8.554.20160
ASP.NET Core Razor Language Services   16.1.0.2052803+84e121f1403378489b842e1797df2f3f5a49ac3c
ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2019   16.8.554.20160
Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0   16.8.554.20160
Azure Data Lake Node   1.0
Azure Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio   2.6.3000.0
Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools   16.8.554.20160
Azure Stream Analytics Tools for Visual Studio   2.6.3000.0
C# Tools   3.8.0-5.20604.10+9ed4b774d20940880de8df1ca8b07508aa01c8cd
Common Azure Tools   1.10
Extensibility Message Bus   1.2.6 (master@34d6af2)
Fabric.DiagnosticEvents   1.0
GitHub.VisualStudio   2.11.106.19330
IntelliCode Extension   1.0
Microsoft Azure HDInsight Azure Node   2.6.3000.0
Microsoft Azure Hive Query Language Service   2.6.3000.0
Microsoft Azure Service Fabric Tools for Visual Studio   16.0
Microsoft Azure Stream Analytics Language Service   2.6.3000.0
Microsoft Azure Stream Analytics Node   1.0
Microsoft Azure Tools   2.9
Microsoft Continuous Delivery Tools for Visual Studio   0.4
Microsoft JVM Debugger   1.0
Microsoft Library Manager   2.1.113+g422d40002e.RR
Microsoft MI-Based Debugger   1.0
Microsoft Visual C++ Wizards   1.0
Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Containers   1.1
Microsoft Visual Studio VC Package   1.0
Mono Debugging for Visual Studio   16.8.43 (00471f8)
Node.js Tools   1.5.20902.1 Commit Hash:b474efcb6f92db52a8f8e2e6a8cb9648476885cc
NuGet Package Manager   5.8.0
ProjectServicesPackage Extension   1.0
Snapshot Debugging Extension   1.0
SQL Server Data Tools   16.0.62010.06180
ToolWindowHostedEditor   1.0
TypeScript Tools   16.0.21016.2001
Visual Basic Tools   3.8.0-5.20604.10+9ed4b774d20940880de8df1ca8b07508aa01c8cd
Visual F# Tools   16.8.0-beta.20507.4+da6be68280c89131cdba2045525b80890401defd
Visual Studio Code Debug Adapter Host Package   1.0
Visual Studio Container Tools Extensions   1.0
Visual Studio Tools for Containers   1.0
Visual Studio Tools for Kubernetes   1.0
Visual Studio Tools for Unity   4.8.2.0
VisualStudio.DeviceLog   1.0
VisualStudio.Foo   1.0
VisualStudio.Mac   1.0
Xamarin   16.8.000.260 (d16-8@fd405a2)
Xamarin Designer   16.8.0.507 (remotes/origin/d16-8@e87b24884)
Xamarin Templates   16.8.112 (86385a3)
Xamarin.Android SDK   11.1.0.17 (d16-8/c0e2b8e)
Xamarin.Android Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support.
    Mono: be2226b
    Java.Interop: xamarin/java.interop/d16-8@79d9533
    ProGuard: Guardsquare/proguard/proguard6.2.2@ebe9000
    SQLite: xamarin/sqlite/3.32.1@1a3276b
    Xamarin.Android Tools: xamarin/xamarin-android-tools/d16-8@2fb1cbc
Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac SDK   14.6.0.15 (87a1b18d8)
Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support.
```

Comment: Looks like build is already failing. Did you manage to see which are the build errors ? also did you isolate which tests are culprit ? Are your regular tests building and passing correctly ? You can decorate suspected test class or test methods with ` [TestCategory("SkipWhenLiveUnitTesting")]` to help find out or as workaround to livetest the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up with an unused Nuget reference in my .csproj file - not sure why that would make a difference, but when I removed the reference, Live Unit Testing started working again.